# Attempt to convert a a buffer file working in node but not in PHP

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, openssl, php-openssl

I'm trying to find a solution, but it's impossible.

I have an encrypted audio file that I can decrypt with NodeJS.

But with PHP, I'm not far, but some imperfection on the output file. (The file is 98% OK but at some point you can hear little skips. Which are not present when the decryption is done from Node)

Here is how I proceeded:

1. Load buffer + buffer size.
2. Separation of the buffer into chunks of 2048 bytes.
3. Looping on this chunks. (In this loop verify if a condition if need to decrypt this part of chunk or not and appending the chunk into decrypted buffer)

Here is my NodeJS Part :

```
    let decBuffer = Buffer.alloc(tBuffer.length);
    let chunkSize = 2048;
    let p = 0;

    while (p < tBuffer.length) {
        if ((tBuffer.length - p) < 2048) {
            chunkSize = tBuffer.length - p;
            isLast = true;
        }
        let chunk = tBuffer.slice(p, p + chunkSize);
    
        // Only decrypt every third chunk and only if not at the end
        if (p % (chunkSize * 3) === 0 && chunkSize === 2048) {
            let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('bf-cbc', k, Buffer.from([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
            cipher.setAutoPadding(false);
            chunk = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(chunk), cipher.final()]);
        }
        decBuffer.write(chunk.toString('binary'), p, chunk.length, 'binary');
        p += chunkSize;
    }


    return decBuffer;
```

And my PHP part

```
    $tBuffer = implode('', file('encrypted.mp3'));
    $tChunks = str_split($tBuffer, 2048);
    $f           = fopen('decrypted.mp3', 'ab+');
    $p    = 0;

    foreach ($tChunks as $chunk)
    {
        $chunkSize = strlen($chunk);

        if (($p % ($chunkSize * 3) == 0) && $chunkSize == 2048)
        {
            $chunk = openssl_decrypt($chunk, 'bf-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, '01234567');
        }

        fwrite($f, $chunk);
        $p += $chunkSize;
    }
    fclose($f);
```

Thanks for thoses who can help me in advance !

Have a good day !

Comment: “at some point” is vague. You should be able to perform a binary diff of the Node and PHP versions to see exactly how they differ. Hopefully it is just a bite or two in drift that can be easily corrected.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, here are the files in question. (https //we. (dot) tl/t-Y3lrgRGqdw)

If you have time to look at the buffers they are not really the same, but the sound is almost the same... I can't find a solution really. It's impossible to have the same beginning of the buffer